# Charging/USB Notification Not Appearing on LG X Charge

Tags: adb, usb, linux, usb-debugging, lg

For the past month I have been trying to connect my phone to my Ubuntu Linux with little luck- for context, I used to run Linux Mint and managed to get things to work just fine. However, I switched over to Ubuntu, and when I tried to set up ADB again, it mysteriously just refused to list the device. The phone still *charges,*  but nothing detects it; not `mtp-detect`, not `lsusb`, not `adb devices`. It does not show the charging notification, no matter what (and I know for I fact I haven't muted the notification or anything like that. It *used* to show the charging notification, but unfortunately I can't pinpoint exactly when it stopped.)

Initially, I thought it was a data transfer/charge only cable issue, so I checked maybe twenty cables and not a single one of them worked. I then figured it may be a problem with Ubuntu, being as I'm pretty inexperienced with the OS (and Linux in general). A bunch of package re-installations later, still no change. Also tried several other computers (non-Linux), none of them detected the phone either.

...And *then* I tried another, identical LG X Charge phone; exact same Developer options, same model number, same firmware version... and it *worked instantly, charging notification and everything.* The only difference between the two is that this other phone has never been connected to the Ubuntu computer. It was connected with the same USB cable and through the same port. (Also, yes, both phones were unlocked.)

I'm kind of at a loss at this point- I've tried revoking USB debugging authorizations, I've changed the USB configuration to everything under the sun, I've tried doing it in Safe Mode... I've even done a factory reset on my phone, and *still* no dice. At this point, I'm convinced it's an issue with the phone's USB port itself, but I have absolutely no idea what would make it suddenly react like this. There hasn't been any external damage to the port between me switching computer OS' as far as I'm aware of. The only other theory I have is that, somehow, when I installed Ubuntu, it messed up the authorization and the phone *thinks* it's still authorized when it's not- though it wouldn't explain it being unrecognized by other computers, and one would think revoking the authorizations would've fixed it...

If further specifications are required, I'd be happy to supply. `Adb devices` simply has a blank space under 'List of devices attached' when ran, and `mtp-detect` says 'No raw devices found', while the other phone is detected by both of these.

**EDIT**
I am still seeking information on this- if I'm correct in my assumption that it's an issue on the phone's port end, does anybody have any idea how I would go about fixing this, or am I just gonna have to get a new phone...?
This is all especially pressing as, it turns out, when I factory reset my phone, I found out my backup hadn't actually backed up *everything-* so I would definitely like to have some sort of solution or even *idea* of what the issue is so I don't repeat a mistake like that in the future.

Comment: I suggest you get the usb port replaced. Get a rough quotation from reputed repair shops and see whether repairing or buying a new phone makes more sense.